# How to create an object of file content in Java?

Tags: java, object, attributes

I want to make arrays, with information of a text file.

This is what the file looks like:

```
ANIMAL         FEET        TAIL       DANGEROUS      COLOR
Dog            4           Yes        No             Brown
Spider         8           No         Yes            Black
Snake          0           No         Yes            Green
```

Separated by tabs.

I want to create an object of each animal, with the number of feet, the tail and the color as attributes.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: You need to post your code,  first. We're not going to write it for you.

Comment: Please include code that you have tried and your expected output in your question

Answer (score 1):

You haven't posted an attempt so I'm not going to attempt that for you, but just a tip that you can use in problems like these is that you can create a class to represent this information like this. In your question you are wanting to use an Array; which isn't the best way of doing things and you've also tagged your question with [object](/questions/tagged/object).

First of all you can read your text file in line by line, at each stage you can create an `Animal` object which can look something like:

```
class Animal {

    private String name;
    private int feet;
    private boolean tail, dangerous;
    private String color;

    public Animal(){

    }

    public Animal(String name, int feet, boolean tail, boolean dangerous, String color){
        this.name = name;
        this.feet = feet;
        this.tail = tail;
        this.dangerous = dangerous;
        this.color = color;
    }

    // getters and setters for these fields here

}
```

Because you have many animals from this textfile, you might find it useful to do something along the lines of:

```
ArrayList<Animal> animals = new ArrayList<>();
for(each line of the textfile you read){
    animals.add(new Animal(...));
}
```

This is the part where arrays can be helpful.